# Queryset return response customize

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm pretty new to Django restframework, what i'm trying now is to return object with foreignkey.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modiefied = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    home = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    work = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    mobileNo = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    appVersionCode = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    photoUrl = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    serverTime = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    fcmTokenId = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
   def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class LocationData(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(
     User, related_name='user', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    source_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    speed = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    kms = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_modiefied = models.DateTimeField(auto



class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = '__all__'

class LocationDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 

class Meta:
    model = LocationData
    fields = '__all__'
    depth = 1
```

I'm using def get_queryset(self):

```
class SyncIndexLastDataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = LocationDataSerializer

def get_queryset(self):

    userid = self.request.query_params.get('user_id', None)
    userExist = User.objects.filter(id=userid)
    if userExist.exists():
        # call the original 'list' to get the original response
        queryset = LocationData.objects.values('source_id').filter(user__id=userid).order_by('-source_id')[:1]
        lastSourceId = queryset[0]['source_id']
        response = {"collection": {"data": lastSourceId,"statusCode": status.HTTP_200_OK,"version":"1.0"}}
        json = JSONRenderer().render(response)
        # customize the response data
        if response is not None:
            return json
    else:
        # return response with this custom representation
        response = {"collection": {"data": "","statusCode":status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,"version":"1.0","error":"Not found"}}
        return response
```

Right now the result is inside the response is below and immediately it throws this error

But i want that queryset to return as below one, Hence i can read those key-pair values in android

```
{ "collection": {
  "data": {
    "id": 31,
    "source_id": "55",
    "latitude": "24654",
    "longitude": "454654",     
    "date_created": "2019-02-08T17:10:09.318644Z",
    "date_modiefied": "2019-02-08T17:10:09.318714Z",
    "area": "54546",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Dormy",
        "date_created": "1992-01-18T03:29:53.388000Z",
        "date_modiefied": "2018-02-19T05:17:00.164000Z",
        "serverTime": "",
        "fcmTokenId": ""
      }
  },
    "statusCode": 200,
    "version": "1.0"
 }
```

Now the error throws

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `source_id` on serializer `LocationDataSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `int` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'int' object has no attribute 'source_id'.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want all of your response in this way or just special type of request - response ?

Comment: By the above way I mentioned!

Comment: you can add annotate in your query. Using that you can add custom field to your query

Comment: @Sarang do you have sample! Please post it

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate check this link. There are many functionalities which you can use with annotate.

Comment: I have updated the issue and more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since get_queryset won't allow you to customize the response data. I decide to take the query value that's important to me.

**http://localhost/api/users/?user_id=1 --> changed into ...api/users/1**

```
 def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """ userid = self.request.query_params.get('user_id', None) """

    userid = kwargs.get('pk')
    userExist = User.objects.filter(id=userid)
    if userExist.exists():
        # call the original 'list' to get the original response
        queryset =  LocationData.objects.values('source_id').filter(user__id=userid).order_by('-source_id')[:1]
        lastSourceId = queryset[0]['source_id']
        response = {"collection": {"data": lastSourceId,"statusCode": status.HTTP_200_OK,"version":"1.0"}}
        # customize the response data
        if response is not None:
            return Response(response)
    else:
        # return response with this custom representation
        response = {"collection": {"data": "","statusCode":status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,"version":"1.0","error":"Not found"}}
        return response
```

Comment: So a few pointers. 1) You should update your docstring, currently it is just a code sample with no relevance to the method. 2) response can never be none as you define it immediately above so `if response is not None` is redundant. 3) you really should not be returning the status code as part of the response body. You should set the status in the response like `return Response(response, status=404)`.

Comment: Yup, Taken care of all things stated!. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this depends on what type of view you are using but the bottom line is you don't do this in `get_queryset` you do this in the method for the type of reguest.

For example if you are using a [RetrieveAPIView](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L204) you should override the `retrieve` method from the [RetrieveModelMixin](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L51) like so:

```py
class MyAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        data = {
            "collection": {
                "data": serializer.data
            },
            "statusCode": 200,
            "version": "1.0"
        }
        return Response(data)
```

If you are using something else like a ListAPIView then you want to see what is used by that in the relevant method and override that to wrap your data.

The main thing to realise here is that it has nothing to do with getting the queryset - which is just about getting data from the database. This is about transforming the data into the correct format when sending back a response. As a result the work should be done at the point the response is made.

Comment: How about the         queryset = LocationData.objects.filter(user__id=userid).order_by('-source_id')[:1]
?
 I need to filter the queryset and provide that data to response!

Comment: You can either filter in `get_queryset`, or call `get_queryset` in the method I mentioned in my answer and filter the value it returns.

Comment: an example would be great!, i don't find any clue to do that!

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of solution possible for this problem. NDevox already mention how we can overwrite our `retrive` function and get our expected response. But If we want this will be done with every response for every `api` end-point and if we go this way we need to overwrite every function then its quite burden and its `DRY` we should avoid this as possible. One of the possible way to introduce a middleware or overwrite `Response` so that we can get our generic response for every-api end-point without explicitly overwrite every functionality.

#### Possible Solution One

As we are using `DRF` here we can add our own return responses with various media types, say for `application/json`.

First We need to add in our settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'app_name.renderers.ApiRenderer',  # our own render middleware
    ),
    ...
}
```

And in our custom render middleware

```
from rest_framework.renderers import BaseRenderer
from rest_framework.utils import json


class ApiRenderer(BaseRenderer):

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        our_response_dict = {
            'version': '1.0'
            'data': {},
            'message': '',
        }
        if data.get('data'):
            our_response_dict['data'] = data.get('data')
        if data.get('status'):
            our_response_dict['statusCode'] = data.get('status')
        if data.get('message'):
            our_response_dict['message'] = data.get('message')
        data = our_response_dict
        return json.dumps(data)
```

Reference [Link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/)

#### Possible Solution Two

If we are using `ModelViewset` then there is another way we can achievement that. Say Our Views.py are like following

```
class A(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    ........

class B(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    ........


class C(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    ........
```

Our goal is to overwrite `ModelViewset`'s to_representation function and return our custom result. This will like as following

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class OurParentViewset(serializer.ModelSerializer):

    ......
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(serializers.ModelSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        result = OrderedDict()
        result['data'] = data
        result['version'] = '1.0'
        result['statusCode'] = '2xx' # i am not fully sure how to customize this
        return result

    class A(OurParentViewset):
        ........

    class B(OurParentViewset):
        ........


    class C(OurParentViewset):
        ........
```

Comment: @Tot sir your can't just change the defination/response of quest_set. As you are using `ModelViewset` please go through RetrieveModelMixin [link](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py) , Here you will find what is actually happening under `retrive` of ModelViewset and you can see that after query_set are passing to Serializer and as you are using ModelSerializer there is no `collection` section there.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing a custom renderer here seems to be a ways to go.

You can have requests from your android client include in the `Accept` header a way to identify the client to the renderer. <sup>[1](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#ordering-of-renderer-classes)</sup> *e.g.*

```
Accept: application/json; android=true
```

Then compose a renderer using the `JSONRenderer` class to provide the format for your Android client.

```
# ./formatters/android_format.py

from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer, BaseRenderer
from django.http.multipartparser import parse_header

class AndroidV1FormatRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'application/json'
    format = 'json'

    json_renderer = JSONRenderer()

    def android(self, accepted_media_type):
        base_media_type, params = parse_header(accepted_media_type.encode('ascii'))
        return 'android' in params

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        response = renderer_context['response']
        android = self.android(accepted_media_type)
        if android:
            data = {
                "collection": {"data": data},
                "statusCode": response.status_code,
                "version": "1.0"
            }

        return json_renderer.render(
            wrapped_data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

This can then be used where you require response formatted that way using `renderer_classes` attribute of your `APIView`. <sup>[2](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-renderers)</sup>